# Bootstrap Navbar Collapse Icon Not Appearing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my website at http://www.dealmazing.com

If I view my website in mobile, the collapse icon disappears although you can click on the area in order to toggle/expand the menu.

Here is my relevant HTML code for my nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg justify-content-between navbar-dark bg-primary royalblue">
     <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/dealmazing_logo.png' %}" class="img-fluid" style="height:50px;" alt="dealmazing deals logo"></a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
```

I did recently compress my CSS and JS and I think there may be an issue with the formatting of the toggle icon but i'm not sure how to fix it.

I did add this code to my custom CSS but doesn't seem to be working

```
.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Remember that questions should be helpful to future readers. Please post the relevant code in the question instead of linking to external sites that may change over time.

Comment: ok will do--posting now

Comment: It is not showing because you are not properly using base64 strings. Rather then dropping in the raw base64, just save a copy of your icon locally and link to the svg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

image url should be:

```
data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20viewBox='0%200%2030%2030'%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath%20stroke='rgba(255,%20255,%20255,%200.5)'%20stroke-width='2'%20stroke-linecap='round'%20stroke-miterlimit='10'%20d='M4%207h22M4%2015h22M4%2023h22'/%3E%3C/svg%3E
```

or store image locally to use it.

Comment: ok thanks, i updated my css to use this image exactly like you said, but still not working.  when i view live site, i see this link:  `url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3CsvgviewBox='003232'xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpathstroke='rgba(255,255,255,0.9)`

Comment: ok got it to work, turns out my css selectors were off a bit. thank you